# Image not displaying correctly within a div after imagejpeg

Tags: php, ajax, image, jpeg

I have a simple page which loads links, the links change the look of an image. I want an ajax call to process the image (pixelate it or something or other) and then update the results within a div, but its not diplaying properly, just a collection of e.g. `���X!t��⤹9�Ej_5��-`

I have tried using `header('Content-Type: image/jpg');` at the top of the page containing the div to be populated but that results in "This image cannot be displayed as it has errors"

here is the php:

```
$im = '/path/to/image.jpg';
if($_GET[filter]=="pixelate"){
imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_PIXELATE, 3, true);
imagejpeg($im);
}
```

AJAX

```
function addFilter(filter,color)
{
$.ajax({

 type: "GET",
 url: 'filters.php',
 data: {filter: filter, color: color},
 success: function(data) {
       // data is ur summary
      $('#result').html(data);
 }

});

}
```

And HTML

```
<div style="width:600px; height:400px;" id="result"></div>
<a href="#" onclick="addFilter('pixelate','')">pixelate</a>
```

**QUESTION** How do I get image to display? Do I have to copy the image to a temp dir to show it as actualy image?

Comment: Why not just change the `img src` with the link you are hovering over using jQuery?

Comment: @Steven Not sure what you mean?

Comment: You have an DIV containig an image - right?`And you want to change this image when you click a link?

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$im = '/path/to/image.jpg';
if($_GET[filter]=="pixelate"){
    imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_PIXELATE, 3, true);
    imagejpeg($im);
}
```

To:

```
if($_GET[filter]=="pixelate"){
    $im = @imagecreatefromjpeg('/path/to/image.jpg');
    if ($im) {
        imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_PIXELATE, 3, true);
        header('Content-Type: image/jpg');
        imagejpeg($im);
        imagedestroy($im);
        exit;
    } else {
       echo 'Unable to create image from jpeg.';
       exit;
    }
}
```